# Removal of x and y axes lines in ListPlot

Tags: plotting

I want to plot some data files through this code:-

```
Needs["CustomTicks`"];
SetOptions[LinTicks, MajorTickLength -> {0.035, 0}, 
  MinorTickLength -> {0.015, 0}];
ticks2 = {{LinTicks, StripTickLabels[LinTicks]}, {LinTicks, 
    StripTickLabels[LinTicks]}};

x = RandomReal[{-0.1, 0.5}, 100];
y = RandomReal[{-0.1, 0.5}, 100];
data = Transpose[{x, y}];

ListPlot[{data}, PlotRange -> {{-0.2, 0.5}, {-0.1, 0.55}}, 
 PlotRangeClipping -> True, AspectRatio -> 1.0, Frame -> True, 
 BaseStyle -> Directive[Bold, FontFamily -> "Times", 18], 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick], ImageSize -> 400, 
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, FrameTicks -> ticks2, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Lighter[Red], Thick]}, Joined -> True]
```

The output that mathematica gives:-
[image: plot]

Now the problem is in the plot the x and y axis is automatically come, which annoying me. How I can remove these two lines from the plot?

Comment: Does adding the option `Axes -> False` do what you want?

Comment: to the author of the OP: @MichaelE2 gave you the answer. I am suggesting here a Minimal Working Example (MWE) and perhaps you can consider updating your question such that it is relevant to other users as well. With the random data `x = RandomReal[{-0.1, 0.5}, 100]; y = RandomReal[{-0.1, 0.5}, 100]; data = Transpose[{x, y}];` if you execute `ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> {{-0.2, 0.5}, {-0.1, 0.55}}, Frame -> True]` you still get the lines inside the `ListPlot`. Michael's solution resolved this. Please, consider this toy model for your post. Many thanks!

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @bmf thanks for your suggestion!